# Swift. How to set custom number format? With space thouthand separator and two digits after point

Tags: swift, string, formatting, format, nsnumberformatter

I need separate thouthands with space, and two digit after point.

```
let d1: Double = 20000000.0
let d2: Double = 1.2345
```

I want to view:

```
let s1 = String(format: "????", d1) //20 000 000.00
let s2 = String(format: "????", d2) //1.23
```

How to do it?

Comment: Apparently you already know about NumberFormatter – so where exactly is the problem? Did you check its various properties and methods to control the number of fractional digits and the thousands separator?

Comment: I searched this problem. I can Separate thouthands with space, or limit two digit after point - but separately. I need combine both cases to one.

Comment: Then your question should have been: “It tried this ... and that ... and the results were ..., but not ... as expected.”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```swift
let d1: Double = 20000000.0
let d2: Double = 1.2345

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.groupingSeparator = " "
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.decimalSeparator = "." // Default separator is dependent to the current local.

print(formatter.string(for: d1)) // 20 000 000.00
print(formatter.string(for: d2)) // 1.23
```

Comment: Note that this will change the decimal separator depending on the users locale. If one always wants it to be a dot (.) it is best to set the locale as `formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")`

Comment: No need to initialize a new `NSNumber` object. You can use `Formatter`\`s method `string(for: Any)`. `formatter.string(for:  d1)`

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I update the answer. @JoakimDanielson I used the `decimalSeparator` property instead of creating a new `Locale` to force the separator style tho.